# time complexity of concatenating strings in python

Tags: python, time-complexity

What is is the time complexity for the following function in Python? 
The function takes two inputs, string1 and string2, concatenates them together using "+" and returns the concatenated string.

```
def concat_strings(string1, string2):
    return string1 + " " + string2
```

is it O(n + m) where n is the length of string1 and m is the length of string2?
thanks!

Comment: How could it be anything else? Is there a particular reason you're unsure?

Comment: You can assume this is linear, yes. I could imagine a faster implementation. But generally you do not / should not reason about the time complexity of these kind of internal operations. Same as `int1 + int2` - is considered constant even though it technically can be larger for very large ints.

Comment: i'm not sure...i'm fairly new to time-complexity and from what i've seen online string concatenation is not simple

Comment: @kaya3 yes, it could be something else. It could be, for instance, `O(n)` or `O(m)`, if strings were represented as linked lists (as it is in some languages), or even `O(1)` if they were doubly-linked lists. This really depends how Python represents strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. Strings in Python are immutable, once-allocated data. So when you do `string1 + string2`, it will allocate a size `n+m`, then copy both strings.

Comment: so does that mean that if i would modify the function to only take one argument, `string1`, and it returns `"the string is " + string1` then the time complexity would be O(n) where n is the length of string1?

Comment: @user19245296 from the Big O notation point of view, yes, as you have only one variable.

Comment: @user19245296 yes, because that would be `O(n+m)`, and since `m` is constant `O(n+m)=O(n)`.